# Get previous element with specific data (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have db.

Here is screen

[image]

Here is model of db.

```
public partial class Logging
{
    public string Imei { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurDateTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> GPSDateTime2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Latitude2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Longitude2 { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Datatype { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I need to find difference in minutes between entry where `datatype == 1` and previous element where `datatype == 2`

on back-end I make this code to get all data from table

```
using (var ctx = new GoogleMapTutorialEntities())
{
    var allitems = ctx.Loggings.AsEnumerable().Select(
            x => new Logging
            {
                Longitude2 = x.Longitude2,
                Latitude2 = x.Latitude2,
                CurDateTime = x.CurDateTime,
                Datatype = x.Datatype

            }).ToList(); 
}
```

How I can calculate difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Ticks` property of the `DateTime` and pass it to a `TimeSpan` in order to get the time difference in minutes (`TotalMinutes`). For example:

```
for(int i = 1; i < yourQuery.Count; i++){
    var differenceTicks = yourQuery[i].CurDateTime.Ticks - yourQuery[i-1].CurDateTime.Ticks;
    var differenceInMinutes = new TimeSpan(differenceTicks).TotalMinutes;
    // You can assign this value to any property within your list or 
    // to another list
}
```

Update:

To filter the query with the `DataType` property, you should call the `.Where(...)` method and you can use it this way:

```
 var filteredQuery = query.Where(x=> x.DataType == 1 || x.DataType == 2);
```

Update 2:

The problem you described in your comment is more complex and to solve this problem you need to take advantage of the Record Id/Row Identifier in actual table. Assuming that id is simply the `id` property in your model, it can be done as follows:

```
var filteredQuery = query.Where(x=> x.DataType == 1 || x.DataType == 2).OrderByDescending(x=> x.id);
for(int i = 1; i < filteredQuery.Count; i++){
    if(filteredQuery[i].DataType == 2 && filteredQuery[i-1].DataType == 1){
        // Then calculate the difference as described 
    }
}
```

You may need to tune the conditions in the loop according to what exactly you need.

> Keep in mind that you may get a result in which `DateType == 2` may
>   not correspond to `DataType == 1` as the data in between might have
>   been already removed in the database. To tackle this issue simply check if the `current id is equal to previous id + 1`. This only works if the id is not a GUID type (not even a sequential GUID) and of course not in Alphabetic form or generated by random functions.

Comment: Hm. My question is mainly about how to get CurDateTime of entry with datatype ==1 and datatype ==2.

Comment: Bacause as you can see between this entries I can have entry with datatype ==0

Comment: okay. filtering works. Now I have List with datatypes in this order 1,2,1,2

So it will take difference between 2 and 1, 1 and 2 ,and 2 and 1 as I understood.

Comment: And I need to take difference only if datatype ==1 have datatype == 2 before

Comment: Have only one trouble in this row `var differenceInMinutes = new TimeSpan(differenceTicks).TotalMinutes;` I have error 
`Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.TimeSpan' to 'long'`

Comment: I think, I can solve it via rewrite it like this `TimeSpan differenceTicks = filteredQuery[i].CurDateTime - filteredQuery[i - 1].CurDateTime;
                        var differenceInMinutes = (int)differenceTicks.TotalMinutes;`

Comment: @S.E: I fixed it, I had forgotten to add `.Ticks` at the end of `yourQuery[i].CurDateTime`